Stanza annotation cannot recognize date and id cardinals
I am playing with the annotation tool provided by Stanford stanza according to the beginners guide. The input of the experiment is the questions from Bird dev dataset. There are some entities in the questions and I expect the annotation would mark them all. However, it seems like the entity extraction tool does not work as expected.
The code is totally extracted from the beginners guide
import stanza

stanza.download("en")
en_nlp = stanza.Pipeline("en")
question = "For the client who first applied the loan in 1993/7/5, what is the increase rate of his/her account balance from 1993/3/22 to 1998/12/27?"
en_doc = en_nlp(question)
entities = en_doc.ents

Is there any way I can improve the accuracy of the entity extraction?
For example

For the client who first applied the loan in 1993/7/5, what is the increase rate of his/her account balance from 1993/3/22 to 1998/12/27?

The output of entity only contains 2 entities:
first:ORDINAL 1993/7/5:DATE while the expected result should include the last 2 dates. The result is bizarre for me since it recognizes the first date and missed the other two.

What type of credit card does the client with the id 13539 own?

The output is null while 13539 should be detected.

What is the sum that client number 4's account has following transaction 851? Who owns this account, a man or a woman?

The entity 851 was identified as cardinal while the client number 4 was not listed.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
